# Blank page and following error in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop

In prestashop it show blank page both side fron end and backend some time show following error:

```
[PrestaShop] Fatal error in module smarty_internal_write_file:
Uncaught --> Smarty: unable to write file D:\Hosting\11513307\html\Shop/cache/smarty/compile\50\d0\37\wrt547ffab5121125_65960237
```

<-- thrown

Comment: `\html\Shop/cache/` - very interesting directory structure..

Answer (score 0):

Your Smarty Cache directory either does not exist or it does not have write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

please provide `write` permission to the directory.

```
D:\Hosting\11513307\html\Shop/cache/smarty/compile\50\d0\37\
```